# No se puede ejecutar un programa simple en Visual Studio Code sin este error,

Tags: c++, vscode

Tengan en cuenta que instalé el compilador de microsoft c ++ y también descargué la versión portátil

```
"g ++" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
executable program or batch file.
```

Comment: ¿ Que nombre tiene el compilador que has instalado ? ¿ Seguro que se llama `g++` ?

Comment: No es g++, es c/c++ de microsoft

Comment: Y entonces ... ¿ Porqué estás intentando ejecutar un programa que no tienes ?

Comment: Yo sólo trato de hacer un código de hello world, pero me aparece este error.

Comment: VSCode está configurado para funcionar con el compilador `gcc` que no has instalado, y no con el compilador de Microsoft. Quieres hacer una de estas cosas. 1) Desinstalar VSCode y instalar Visual Studio (estos son dos productos diferentes). 2) Desinstalar el compilador de Microsoft y instalar gcc. 3) Configurar manualmente VSCode para que funcione con el compilador de Microsoft en lugar de gcc.